# My signed transaction seems failed, and not broadcasted. why?

Tags: ethereumjs, raw-transaction

I want to do a very simple operation: send eth to another address.

Here is what I did:

#### Method 1 . use personal.send_transaction JSON-RPC interface. ( seems deprecated )

I run:

```bash
curl --request POST   --data '{
    "jsonrpc":"2.0",
    "method":"personal_sendTransaction",
    "params":[
      {
        "gas": "0x5208",
        "gasPrice": "0x178411b200",
        "from": "0x7CCfaF74ADBA37b2eF11B4caa3ce3759xxxxxxxx",
        "to": "0x3Ae7a18407B17037B2ECC4901c1b77Dbxxxxxxxx",
        "value": "0x4f94ae6af8000"
      },
      "my_pass_word"
    ],
    "id": 4004
  }'   --header 'Content-Type: application/json' http://172.16.1.53:8800
```

response:

```json
{
    "jsonrpc":"2.0",
    "result":"0x76af9bc26ac39f6011c76c3adf2914ab8b677ad95a8687ed0b3de058d4866bb6",
    "id":4004
}
```

however, this tx could NOT be found in etherscan.

and got this log:

```
2020-12-20 07:45:03 UTC http.worker10 WARN rpc  personal_sendTransaction is deprecated and will be removed in future versions: Account management is being phased out see #9997 for alternatives.
2020-12-20 07:45:03 UTC http.worker10 DEBUG own_tx  Imported to the pool (hash 0x76af9bc26ac39f6011c76c3adf2914ab8b677ad95a8687ed0b3de058d4866bb6)
2020-12-20 07:45:03 UTC http.worker10 DEBUG txqueue  [0x76af9bc26ac39f6011c76c3adf2914ab8b677ad95a8687ed0b3de058d4866bb6] Added to the pool.
2020-12-20 07:45:03 UTC http.worker10 DEBUG txqueue  [0x76af9bc26ac39f6011c76c3adf2914ab8b677ad95a8687ed0b3de058d4866bb6] Sender: 0x7ccf…xxxx, nonce: 887, gasPrice: 101000000000, gas: 21000, value: 1400000000000000, dataLen: 0))
2020-12-20 07:45:03 UTC IO Worker #1 DEBUG sync  Finished transaction propagation, took 0ms
2020-12-20 07:45:03 UTC http.worker10 DEBUG txqueue  Re-computing pending set for block: 11475896
2020-12-20 07:45:03 UTC http.worker10 DEBUG miner  Attempting to push 1 transactions.
2020-12-20 07:45:03 UTC http.worker10 DEBUG miner  Adding tx 0x76af9bc26ac39f6011c76c3adf2914ab8b677ad95a8687ed0b3de058d4866bb6 took 3 ms
2020-12-20 07:45:03 UTC http.worker10 DEBUG miner  Pushed 1 transactions in 3 ms
2020-12-20 07:45:03 UTC http.worker10 DEBUG rpc  [Some(Num(4004))] Took 42ms
2020-12-20 07:45:03 UTC http.worker10 DEBUG rpc  Response: {"jsonrpc":"2.0","result":"0x76af9bc26ac39f6011c76c3adf2914ab8b677ad95a8687ed0b3de058d4866bb6","id":4004}.
```

#### method 2. called eth_sendRawTransaction to my local ETH node.

I did this following the steps:

Step 2.1 got the private key ( really correct, I promise, I got this via 2 language API , and they are the same! )

```
<my_private_key>
```

Step 2.2 got the signed tx by my code:

```js
const get_raw_tx = function(params){

  console.info("== params:")
  console.info(params)
  const privateKey = Buffer.from(
    params.private_key,
    'hex',
  )

  const txParams = { 
    nonce: params.nonce,
    gasPrice: params.gas_price,
    gasLimit: params.gas_limit,
    to: params.to_address,
    value: params.crypto_amount,
    data: params.data,
  }

  const tx = new EthereumTx(txParams, { chain: 'mainnet', hardfork: 'petersburg' })
  tx.sign(privateKey)
  const serializedTx = tx.serialize()
  const rawTx = '0x' + serializedTx.toString('hex');
  return rawTx
}
```

and HTTP GET method:

- crypto_amount: 0.0013 ETH
- gas_limit: 21000, in hex: 0x5208
- gas_price: 121000000000   ( 121 Gwei)  ,  in hex: 0x1c2c297a00

```
$ curl http://localhost:8000/get_tx?private_key=MY_PRIVATE_KEY&nonce=0x01&gas_price=0x1c2c297a00&gas_limit=0x2710&to_address=0xC6d64494D2042B69aceAd368395f8e4Fxxxxxxxx&crypto_amount=1300000000000000
```

and got this signed TX string:

```
0xf86d820d1b851c2c297a00825208943ae7a18407b17037b2ecc4901c1b77db98367cda87049e57d63540008026a07931b78f0f596f49655d2c0418156f742ffab64cb2c545616d1f3843e4f4f778a026d63f88d6166ec32223c1e850fb9245e4b5df6d50237080684fc933e7ac0e4b
```

Step 2.3 I make a JSON-PRC call like this:

```bash
curl --location --request POST 'http://my-server-ip:port'   --header 'Content-Type: application/json'   --data-raw '{
    "jsonrpc":"2.0",
    "method":"eth_sendRawTransaction",
    "params":["0xf86d820d1b851c2c297a00825208943ae7a18407b17037b2ecc4901c1b77db98367cda87049e57d63540008026a07931b78f0f596f49655d2c0418156f742ffab64cb2c545616d1f3843e4f4f778a026d63f88d6166ec32223c1e850fb9245e4b5df6d50237080684fc933e7ac0e4b"],
    "id": 4004
  }'
```

and this is the response:

```json
{
    "jsonrpc":"2.0",
    "result":"0x06a1958e25ef269346cc79043c4c4343b9df86bf0b135c257b9b7077e7d83bc7",
    "id":4004
}
```

this tx still could not be found on ( http://etherscan.io/tx/0x06a1958e25ef269346cc79043c4c4343b9df86bf0b135c257b9b7077e7d83bc7 )

no error or warning in log.

#### method 3. called infura API

```bash
curl https://mainnet.infura.io/v3/MY-PROJECT-ID     
    -X POST
    -H "Content-Type: application/json"
    -d '{
         "jsonrpc":"2.0",
         "method":"eth_sendRawTransaction",
         "params":["0xf86d820d1b851c2c297a00825208943ae7a18407b17037b2ecc4901c1b77db98367cda87049e57d63540008026a07931b78f0f596f49655d2c0418156f742ffab64cb2c545616d1f3843e4f4f778a026d63f88d6166ec32223c1e850fb9245e4b5df6d50237080684fc933e7ac0e4b"],
         "id":1
       }'
```

and got response from infura:

```json
{
    "jsonrpc":"2.0",
    "id":1,
    "result":"0x5809db5cdbdab054ca7f5f383e59ba6df74e3f5e87a33b90df1b1c6e7d0ae587"
}
```

still, this TX could not be found on etherscan.io

so, could someone help me, why all these methods are failed.

thanks a lot!

p.s.

#### my environment

Ubuntu 18.04 server

client: openethereum ( OpenEthereum/v3.0.1-stable-8ca8089-20200601/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/rustc1.43.1 )

command to launch it: `nohup ./openethereum &`

config file: ( in `.local/share/openethereum/config.toml`)

```
[parity]
mode = "active"
identity = "lueluelue"
[rpc]
apis = ["web3", "eth", "pubsub", "net", "parity", "parity_pubsub", "traces", "rpc", "shh", "shh_pubsub", "personal", "parity_accounts", "secretstore"]
server_threads = 2

port = 8800
interface = "172.my.i.p"

[websockets]
apis = ["web3", "eth", "pubsub", "net", "parity", "parity_pubsub", "traces", "rpc", "shh", "shh_pubsub", "personal"]

[misc]
log_file = "/home/ubuntu/eth.log"
logging = "debug"

[mining]
min_gas_price = 1
```

and I ran the JSON-RPC calls when the block is not completed synced. ( synced to 1 days ago)

Comment: Which ethereum client are you using? geth, openethereum, besu, .... What's the command line used to launch it? Is the client fully synchronized? Is the nonce correct?

Comment: I am using openethereum ( `OpenEthereum/v3.0.1-stable-8ca8089-20200601/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/rustc1.43.1`),  the command line lauching it is `ohup ./openethereum &`,  and I will update my question and put this information on it.

Comment: @Ismael Is it because I run the JSON-RPC calls on the in-completed synced node?  should I wait until it's fully synced? and I am doubting that my `signed tx` is incorrect. how to check it? thanks a lot!

Comment: You can use [eth_getBlockByNumber](https://openethereum.wiki/JSONRPC-eth-module/#eth_getblockbynumber) to obtain the latest block number it should be close to the latest block in any block explorer like etherscan.

Comment: To verify the transaction parameters use a decoder like https://flightwallet.github.io/decode-eth-tx/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I got it: the parameter `nonce` is important!

My fault: I randomly give the `nonce` parameter, which is not valid in some way. ( I don't know )

After searching many posts, I found the `nonce` is important! ( according to https://nonseodion.medium.com/7-easy-steps-to-resolve-cancel-pending-ethereum-transactions-88d7d8bce053 , this post talks about the relation ship between nonce and `pending` transactions )

also this post: https://info.etherscan.com/how-to-cancel-ethereum-pending-transactions   mentioned nonce.

so, to make clear which number should be my address, I created a transaction using MetaMask, and very soon, I got its state:

```
0.204465275198051046 Eth
Nonce: 912

0.202643275198051046 Eth
Nonce: 913     <!---  this should be your next transaction's nonce!
```

[image]

So I changed my code, specified the correct `nonce` , and then my new signed transaction broadcasted in 3 seconds!

^_^